# A função predict() não aceita regressão exponencial no R

Tags: r, regressão

Por favor, tentando realizar uma modelagem paramétrica de análise de sobrevivência e a função `predict()` está retornando um erro de que não reconhece uma variável, porém ela está lá.

Segue exemplo:

```
base=NULL

base$DIAS= c(7,6,8,6,5,5,5,6,6,11,6,4,5,5,5,5,6,4,5,6)

base$DELTA= c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)

base$Protocolo= c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

base$TIPAC= c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)

base=data.frame(base)

modelo <- survreg(Surv(DIAS,DELTA) ~ Protocolo+TIPAC,data= base, dist = "exponential")

ptempo <- predict(modelo , type = "quantile", newdata= data.frame(1), p=1:99/100,se=TRUE)
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objeto 'Protocolo' não encontrado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>No seu código, você usa `base` como argumento `data`, mas imagino que você quis dizer `modelo`. Não é uma boa prática você usar um mesmo nome de variável para objetos completamente diferentes também (o data frame e a regressão).</strike> (Modificado após edição do AP)

Voltando ao seu problema, o erro ocorre porque você passa um data frame que não possui uma coluna chamada `Protocolo` quando chama o `predict`. Você deve passar um novo conjunto de dados do mesmo formato que os dados utilizados na regressão (com as mesmas variáveis utilizadas na fórmula), ou deixar em branco, para realizar a predição com os dados iniciais. O código abaixo funciona:

```
base <- data.frame(DIAS = c(7,6,8,6,5,5,5,6,6,11,6,4,5,5,5,5,6,4,5,6),
                     DELTA = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0),
                     Protocolo = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                     TIPAC = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))

library(survival)
modelo <- survreg(Surv(DIAS, DELTA) ~ Protocolo + TIPAC, data = base, dist = "exponential")

ptempo <- predict(modelo , type = "quantile", p = 1:99/100, se = TRUE)
str(ptempo)
# List of 2
#  $ fit   : num [1:20, 1:99] 0.1285 0.0929 0.1285 0.1228 0.0929 ...
#  $ se.fit: num [1:20, 1:99] 0.0587 0.0552 0.0587 0.0701 0.0552 ...
```

Comment: Boa noite Molx, obrigado pela ajuda, eu criei uma base para usar de exemplo (a que chamei erroneamente de modelo) e copiei o log da execução do R, cujo nome do data frame era base. O seu comando funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Comment: Quando se retira o argumento "newdata= data.frame(1)"  a ptempo$fit fica com um tamanho desproporcional (de 99 para 14530 no programa original) e não consigo plotar um gráfico. Por favor, o que seria esse argumento? e por que a presença dele impede que o programa reconheça a variável procolo?

Comment: @HenriquePizarro O argumento `p` é, segundo o help da função, "um vetor de percentis. Usado apenas para predição de quantis". O resultado é uma matriz com várias colunas porque ele faz uma predição para cada quantil, no seu caso, são 99 quantis. Se você não pretende utilizar os quantis, pode remover o argumento, e aí sim o resultado vai retornar duas colunas, tanto no `fit` quanto no `se`.